# Oracle Linux update from 7.4 to 7.6 causes gui login loop

Tags: oracle-linux

I have a VM based on VMWare Workstation 14
After upgrading fresh installed `Oracle Linux` from `7.4` to `7.6` and `reboot`, it boots into `Oracle Linux Server 7.6 with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4.1.12-124.2->` (grub entry).
It boots without issues but when I try to log in through gui, it logs me in and after a few seconds throws me out to login screen again.
`Previous kernel is 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 with Unbreakable Enerpr->` (grub entry) - it boots and logs in through gui with the same issue now.
`vt-x` is enabled in bios and in VM settings
Video on the host: Intel hd graphics 530

After booting with newer kernel, then older kernel, then newer kernel again and trying to log in through gui it throws a popup with:

```
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operation system. Power off or reset the virtual machine
```

Error with CPU didn't happen with the older kernel.

I've reinstalled vmware tools, but after trying to log in through gui, it thrown me out and reboot automatically but without a popup about CPU.

The next time I've selected usual kernel (not uek): 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64 in grub menu and it logins without issues.

> I want to install Oracle Database 19c to this system. Could I do it
>   using usual kernel or should I use uek for this purpose?

In case of using UEK I should resolve this issue with logging out, but I've not found solution yet. Maybe I will download 7.6 release - it seems less problematic. But it could be an issue for future in case of upgrading to 7.7 release if it will be released.

Updated. After fresh install of `7.6` release, kernel is: `4.14.35-1818.3.3.el7uek.x86_64` and there's no issues with login. 
After `yum update` `4.14.35-1844.4.5.el7uek.x86_64` kernel was installed without gui login issue.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for that, I have that happen now. I even switched to VMware from Virtualbox thinking its the app that is causing it.
Just keeps on looping. I can ssh into the box but I am sure the looping is causing performance issues.

Comment: @Steve Have you tried not uek kernel?